# In the backend of WordPress, widgets are not loaded completely

Tags: wordpress, widget, admin

In the backend of WordPress, widget page not loaded completely. 
I have tested with 1024M of RAM, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried disabling all of your active plugins, and does this happen with the default TwentySixteen theme as the active theme?

Also PLease check if you are using latest vergion of wordpress or not?

Comment: Thancks, @Vipin